# jQuery: add custom rel attribute to all links inside a div box?

Tags: jquery

I have a lot of div boxes ".box", each filled with more than 3 links. Basically I want to add a rel attribute like this.

- For the first `".box"` add `rel="lightbox[group1]"` to each link inside it
- For the 2nd `".box"` add `rel="lightbox[group2]"` to each link inside it
- For the 3rd `".box"` add `rel="lightbox[group3]"` to each link inside it

My code so far:

```
$('.box a').each(function() { $(this).attr('rel','lightbox[group]'); });
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try this:

```
$(".box").each(function(i) {
    $(this).find("a").attr("rel", "lightbox[group" + (i+1) + "]");
});
```

Comment: darn, 23 seconds too slow..! =) +1

Comment: @DavidThomas It took almost 3 minutes for the answer. That is terribly slow. Evening, evening... :)